# Migration path to crypto.se

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

[Crypto.se is graduating](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/606/congratulations-cryptography-is-graduating).  Does that mean we can finally add an official "vote-to-close" option for our fourth-most-popular migration target?

Comment: I approve of this!